# LINQ Select multiple or statement return distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search multiple columns in multiple data sets which have key constraints. The search feature itself works but when applying .Distinct() an error will return stating it is unable to find a comparable key.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SearchResults(string q)
    {

        var SearchResult = from Result in db.comments select Result;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
        {
            var Found = SearchResult.Where(Result => Result.ticket.summary.ToUpper().Contains(q.ToUpper()) || Result.ticket.main_ticket.Contains(q) || Result.ticket.detailed_description.Contains(q.ToLower()) || Result.ticket.ticket.Contains(q) || Result.comment.Contains(q));
            if (Found== null)
            {
                return Content("No Data.");

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.SearchCount = Found.Count();

                return View(Found.ToList());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("404");
        }
      }
```

//Database tickets

```
||------------------------||
|| ticket_id              ||
|| summary                ||
|| main_ticket            ||
|| detailed_description   ||
|| ticket                 ||
|| comment_id             ||
||------------------------||
```

// Database comments

```
||---------------||
|| comment_id    ||
|| comment       ||
|| RowVerison    ||
||---------------||
```

I know what is happening when I search for the letter T it finds the letter T in comments.comment, tickets.summary and in tickets.detail_description

How do I limit the returned result to distinct key pair?

Should I create a list base on the returned data and then compare the list and only show the Distinct?

Or is there a simpler way that I am over looking?

**[Update - Solution Found]**
Andrei's answer would have been the solution had I been using Model's and not a Controller that interfaced into a .edmx SQLExpress server table. I would suggest using his example before using mine.

While Distinct would not work importing the Ajax Library and using DistinctBy Worked!

```
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
```

I change my Where() line to this

```
var Found = SearchResult.Where(Result => Result.ticket.summary.ToUpper().Contains(q.ToUpper()) || Result.ticket.main_ticket.Contains(q) || Result.ticket.detailed_description.Contains(q.ToLower()) || Result.ticket.ticket.Contains(q) || Result.comment.Contains(q)).DistinctBy(Result => Result.ticket_id).ToList();
```

and removed the .ToList() from my view Return.

```
return View(Found);
```

That returned the correct number of results to my ViewBag.SearchCount and also returned the correct data to my Razor View

```
@model IEnumerable<TICKETS.Controllers.comments>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @ViewBag.SearchCount+ " result(s) for: ";

}


<div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-color panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading"> 
                                <h3 class="panel-title">All Results - @ViewBag.SearchCount Result(s) found.</h3> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                @foreach (var item in Model) {

                                    <h3>          
    <a data_modal="" href="@Url.Action("Details","TICKETS", new{ @id=item.ticket_id})" id="open_modal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tickets.summary)</a>
    </h3>  
    <p>@item.ticket_id :@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tickets.start_date) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tickets.end_date)</p>
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tickets.detailed_description)</p>
    <hr />  
                                }

                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# doesn't know how to compare your Result instances. Thus you need to introduce explicit comparison of your Result class instances.

You need to implement `IEqualityComparer<Result>` interface and pass instance of this interface into your `.Distinct(resultEqualityComparer)` call.

Let's say I have a class User:

```
class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I would compare my User class instances:

```
class UserEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User user1, User user2)
    {
        return user1.Id == user2.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(User user)
    {
        return user.Id;
    }
}
```

**GetHashCode** is a function that should return unique `int` value for different user instances. `Id` would be ideal, if you don't have it, you will have to develop your own formula based on your class properties.

Usage is very simple:

```
var users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "John" });
users.Add(new User { Id = 1, Name = "Lorem" });
users.Add(new User { Id = 2, Name = "Smith" });

users.Distinct(new UserEqualityComparer());
```

As a result, user with the name Lorem will be filtered out of the collection.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I will extend my class to compare using IEqualityComparer. I was 90% that was the route I needed to take...but I guess I was hoping for a simpler solution. Not that your answer isn't simplistic! I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I marked your response as the answer it does and will work IF you have a class Model created. I am using EntityFrame Work with a Database First Approach, so your response while easy to implement forced me to create a class for my controllers. I was able to circumvent that by my updated question. Again thank you very much you pointed me in the correct direction.

Comment: @Chris glad it helped. Good luck